# When I try to extract my minecraft mod from eclipse to a .jar it fails when trying to copy mcmod.info

Tags: command-prompt, minecraft-forge

I've been making a mod for minecraft 1.12.2 through eclipse and after my second week of work (now) I decided I wanna post an early beta for people to give opinions, suggestions, etc. I looked up a tutorial on YouTube that says I need to go to my command prompt, go to my modding file (cd path) and the type "gradlew build". when I type that it displays this error message:
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':processResources'.

> Could not copy file 'C:\Users\vengo\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\ColoriteMod\src\main\resources\mcmod.info' to 'C:\Users\vengo\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\ColoriteMod\build\resources\main\mcmod.info'.

The only thing I understand from that is that when it tried to copy mcmod.info from one place to enother there was a problem. anyone have any ideas?

Comment: See if you can manually copy the file there. You'll probably get an error with details that Gradle didn't show you.

Comment: if you mean copy my mod file directly into my build file, I thought about it but it wouldn't be a .jar so it won't work. I might've misunderstood you though.

Comment: No, I mean manually copy the mcmod.info file to where Gradle tried to put it. When you do it by hand, you'll see the error details.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: just tried moving it, my mcmod.info was already there except nothing written on it. I tried replacing it with the correct one then running the command prompt, assuming that's what you meant, and got the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the error report from command prompt, I realized the content on my mcmodinfo file was wrong, so I tried changing it, and now it works.
If you want to check out my mod, this is the link:
https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/the-colorite-mod